# Firebase Analytics null user ids

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Analytics + BigQuery to track my app. However I noticed that roughly 90% of all events come with null user_dim.user_id parameter. From the logs I found that when calling the FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserId it usually seems to create following log message: "Value is too long; discarded. Value kind, name, value length: user property, _id, 42". So the user ids are being dropped because they are too long. But like the error message implies, the length of the parameter is 42 characters while according to Firebase documentation the maximum length for parameter value is 100 characters. So am I understanding something wrong here or why am I getting "value too long" error when my value is well within the acceptable length?

Here is the full log message (replaced my project name with 'myProject'):

```
03-20 17:11:42.220: I/Unity(22237):  ======== set firebase user id (7f2af34d92074e92af4dc9ffa4f2ace20320150134)  length=42
03-20 17:11:42.291: I/firebase(22237): Firebase App initializing app myProject (default 1).
03-20 17:11:42.292: I/Adjust(22237): Google Play Services Advertising ID read correctly at start time
03-20 17:11:42.292: I/Unity(22237): Firebase App initializing app myProject (default 1).
03-20 17:11:42.292: I/Unity(22237):  
03-20 17:11:42.292: I/Unity(22237): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
03-20 17:11:42.293: I/firebase(22237): Firebase Analytics API Initializing
03-20 17:11:42.293: I/Unity(22237): Firebase Analytics API Initializing
03-20 17:11:42.293: I/Unity(22237):  
03-20 17:11:42.293: I/Unity(22237): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
03-20 17:11:42.293: I/firebase(22237): Firebase Analytics API Initialized
03-20 17:11:42.293: I/Unity(22237): Firebase Analytics API Initialized
03-20 17:11:42.293: I/Unity(22237):  
03-20 17:11:42.293: I/Unity(22237): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
03-20 17:11:43.046: W/FA(22237): Value is too long; discarded. Value kind, name, value length: user property, _id, 42
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

**OLD ANSWER:** Are you using the latest SDK version? The length requirement is enforced differently in latest SDK version. Also, even if you use the latest SDK, but your users don't update to the newer versions, you may still see the errors reported until all of the users update to the newer version.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I mistook your question and I thought you were asking about event parameters. You are setting User Property, not event parameters.

According to the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setUserId(java.lang.String)), the user ID user property must be up to 36 characters long.

> The user ID to ascribe to the user of this app on this device, which must be non-empty and no more than 36 characters long. Setting the ID to null removes the user ID.

The event parameters' limit is 100 instead.

> String parameter values can be up to 100 characters long. The
>   "firebase_" prefix is reserved and should not be used for parameter
>   names.

Comment: We have now updated to the latest SDK but this didn't solve the issue. New users who have started with the new version still give mostly null uids. We do seem to get a little bit less nulls though, now roughly ~70% of all evets come with null user_dim.user_id

Comment: On the new SDK version, do you still get the same warning in the log that the user property is too long if you have user property with > 42 characters?

Comment: This is not really an answer! More details required.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Updated above. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can add `user_id` in User Property tab in firebase console. Then you check if it works for you.